# Restrict root user access to postgres user

Tags: postgresql

I know this is a little weird but bear with me.

If a hacker gains access to a server's root user, he can type "su postgres" and then "psql" and boom - instant access to everything.

I was wondering if there was any possible way to block the root user from switching to the postgres user. In other words, I want to force a postgres-specific password to be used before postgres access is granted.

Is there any way to do this? Or is the root user always God?

Comment: If a hacker gets access to `root` your Postgres database is the least of your worries.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name haha this is very true - still the db data is the only thing that really has me up at night

Comment: Well, you have no chance in this case.  Being `root`, they can change whatever setting in the OS they want, including `su` rights.  If it wasn't so, it would mean a super-root - but then one can gain the super-root access, too.  And then we are back to the original question, and we haven't found a solution.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this might be a better fit on SU.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do what you are asking.

Here's what you should do instead:

- Run your database on its own computer in its own network segment. Don't run anything else on that computer (save backup / monitoring agents)
- Use a separate management network for server management / backup / monitoring
- Send your db + os security logs to another machine and use a software tool to monitor them and send alerts
- Don't connect to database from web servers as a superuser